# How to search for a substring in SQLite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

Whats the most efficient way to search for a sub string in SQLite?

I'm looking at the LIKE operator.

Do I have the right idea? Has this worked well for you?

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Thank You.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes, use `Like`.  A query such as:

```
Select id from sometable where name like '%abc%'
```

would return any row that contained "abc" anywhere in the name column.

If the pattern you are looking for happens to contain the % or _ character, you can use the ESCAPE keyword to define an escape character to include that special character in the expression. To look for the string "somename%" (including the %), it'd look something like:

```
select id from mytable where name like '%somename\%%' escape '\'
```

See: [SQLite Language Expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

Comment: what if the string actually contained the "%" character. What does SQLite do in that case?

Comment: There's an ESCAPE keyword that lets you define an escape character so that you can query on % or _.  See: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html  So you'd do something like "select id from mytable where name like '%somename\%%' escape '\'

Comment: warning: this is case insensitive.

Comment: does it return true if the string starts or ends with 'omm' @GrandmasterB

Comment: @AhmadRajab in that example, it returns all rows that have "omm" anywhere in the string.

Comment: can I use GLOB instead of LIKE to avoid case insensitivity @GrandmasterB

Comment: @AhmadRajab it looks like it, yes.  I don't think that was available back when I first wrote this answer, but it looks like it is something that is available now.

Answer (score 15):

You *can* use `LIKE`, but it gets *really* slow if the pattern you're searching for starts with `'%'` -- i.e., if the substring you're looking for isn't necessarily at the beginning of the field.

If you need to do such searches, consider using [FTS3](http://cvs.hwaci.com/fts3.html), which makes full-text searching considerably more efficient.

Comment: Interesting, is there a lot of overhead to use FTS3? Can it be used with the SQLite API in C?

Comment: @Tommy: I'm not sure what overhead would qualify as a lot from your perspective. Yes, it can be used from the C API.

Comment: The FTS extension is included in the SQLite distribution. You just need to read the docs and turn it on at build time. Note that it will build a non-negligibly sized index with which it works its magic...

Comment: I found this slightly ambiguous. By `If you need to do such searches` do you mean pattern starts at the beginning of the field or does not start at the beginning? Because fts in SQLite doesn't support suffix matches.

Answer (score 9):

Years have passed since the question was asked and answered and in 2012 SQLite version 3.7.15 introduced a function `instr( string, substring)` - returns the location of a substring in a string, 0 if not found. (https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/instr.php)

> sqlite> SELECT instr('TechOnTheNet.com', 'T');
>   Result:  1

I have not benchmarked against `LIKE`, but IMHO could be faster.

Comment: Official docs since edit queue is full: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr This answer feels a lot less hacky too!