# Can't Retrieve data from sqlite database even though the data exists in the database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-studio

Im trying to retrieve some data out of a database called `Train_list` When i try to do so m greeted with the error:

```
D/Final Error: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

After a bit of googling And a bit of Trail and error i realized that the cursor was returning a `null` value So i Questioned if the data was actually being inserted into the database. So i Used a third party plugin ( Or what ever you want to call it ) to see if the data was indeed present in the Database[image]
As You can see the database does indeed have three entries. Now when i Try to read the database with this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        no_name = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Disp_list);
        String message = bundle.getString("package");
        String parameter;
        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(message, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Train_list.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        Cursor header;
        namer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.T1);
        try {
            header = db1.rawQuery("Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no='"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+ "'", null);
            header.moveToFirst();
            String temp = header.getString((header.getColumnIndex("Train_name")));
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "blahhh:"+temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Sucess!","temp:"+temp);
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Gotcha:"+temp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            namer.setText("Train Name: " + temp);
            header.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Final Error",e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(Display_data.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I get the aforementioned error. Some posts suggested adding a '?' but that didnt help either

Heres the code with which i inserted the data:

```
try {
        final String CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Train_list ("
                + "Train_name VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_no VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_start VARCHAR,"
                + "Train_end VARCHAR,"
                + "Seats_Available VARCHAR);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRAIN_LIST);
        Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String sql = "INSERT or replace INTO Train_list (Train_name, Train_no, Train_start, Train_end, Seats_Available) VALUES('"+str_Train_name + "',' " +str_Train_no + "', '" +str_Train_start+"','" +str_Train_end+"',' " +str_Train_seats +"');";
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "train no:"+str_Train_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(admin_manipulation.this, "Sorry Not Inserted Sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Error experienced",e.toString());
        }
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking by getting the cursor count for the query you have run. `header.getCount()` and then do the `header.getString()` only if there is data

```
if (header!= null && header.getCount() > 0){
        header.moveToFirst(); 
  // All the logic of retrieving data from cursor

}
```

Comment: The getcount() returns a value of 0 I dont understand why it does so as we have seen the database does indeed have three entries

Comment: That is the reason for - CursorIndexoutOfBounds exception!

Comment: Check to see if you query is correct or not. Also check if your train number format is correct or not - The one retrieved from - message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))

Comment: If The format weren't correct id be getting a syntax error. That was the error before i encountered this one

Comment: Then you must be giving a wrong train number with no train data

Answer (score 0):

This line in your code:

```
header = db1.rawQuery("Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no='"+message.substring(0,(message.length()-3))+ "'", null);
```

might throw problems depending on the `message` passed in.

If the `Train_no` is supposed to be the train numbers in your table, substringing - 3 looks like it will return only the "aa" portion. Then your rawQuery will look for a `Train_no` that is "aa".

Consider using the LIKE SQL syntax. [This question is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671761/how-to-search-for-a-substring-in-sqlite).

Your query may look like:

```
header = db1.rawQuery("Select Train_name From Train_list Where Train_no like '"+message.substring((message.length()-3), message.length())+ "'", null);
```